# Why does the *ngIf evaluate to true when checked against an observable that is undefined and\or empty object {}?

Tags: angular, observable

Why does this not evaluate to false when error$ object is undefined or an empty object represented as {}? It rather evaluates to true and displays the "Something went wrong" message.

```
`<div *ngIf="(error$ | async) != null">
  <span>Something went wrong {{(error$ | async)?.errorResponse}}</span>
</div>`
```

Thus requiring me to have a boolean property on the error object

```
`<div *ngIf="(error$ | async)?.error">
  <span>Something went wrong {{(error$ | async)?.errorResponse}}</span>
</div>`
```

I know the object is empty `{}` because i subscribe to it in the component and console.log it. I have tried the following ways, none of which work

```
`<div *ngIf="(error$ | async) !== (of({}) | async)">
  <span>Something went wrong {{(error$ | async)?.errorResponse}}</span>
</div>`

`<div *ngIf="(error$ | async) != (of({}) | async)">
  <span>Something went wrong {{(error$ | async)?.errorResponse}}</span>
</div>`

`<div *ngIf="(error$ | async) != '{}'">
  <span>Something went wrong {{(error$ | async)?.errorResponse}}</span>
</div>`

`<div *ngIf="(error$ | async) != undefined">
  <span>Something went wrong {{(error$ | async)?.errorResponse}}</span>
</div>`

`<div *ngIf="(error$ | async) != {}">
  <span>Something went wrong {{(error$ | async)?.errorResponse}}</span>
</div>
`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? The first "Something went wrong" won't display if `error$` is undefined, because `error$ | async` will also evaluate to null/undefined (not sure which, but doesn't matter since you're using non-strict comparison). Anyway, this seems pretty normal.

Comment: When the error$ observable is `{}` the message Something went wrong is displayed.I though that the *ngIf  wont display it if the error$ is null. But it does anyway, thats whats confusing me

Comment: Well, `{}` is different from `null`.

Comment: so should the second and third case cover an empty object?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you don't need another property, you can test for `(error$ | async)?.errorResponse` if you'd like. A cleaner way to solve your issue would be to have `error$` be [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) when there is no error. Then you can simply test with `*ngIf="error$ | async"`. (Not sure if that's doable in your case, hence why I'm not posting this as an answer yet.)

Comment: This is crazy... Im using NGXS, I had my error property initiated to null, then when i started the fetchAll I had used the spread operator error: {...state.posts.error} which had created an empty object. I modified it to use undefined everywhere unless it is an error, and it worked. The spread operator had created an empty object, I didnt know it would do that but i learned that it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the use of the spread operator inside of my state management store. I had started the store error object as null like so `error: null`. Then on my fetchPosts action, I had used the spread operator like so `error: {...state.posts.error}` this in turn created a new empty object `{}`. Thus using the `*ngIf="error$ | async"` always evaluated to true and for some reason checking against empty objects inequalitty like so `*ngIf="(error$ | async) != '{}'"` or `*ngIf="(error$ | async) != (of({}) | async)"` seemed to evaluate to true or not work at all. Instead of the spread operator I used `error: null` and now the `error$ | async` works as expected.